# "heat" or "heating" after a colon

Tags: verb-forms, colons

I'm wondering whether "heat" or "heating" should be used in the following:

> Try this physical experiment: heat/heating air so that it expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some additional context would help in deciding this.

"Heat" sounds more like instructions (the experiment has already been explained), while "heating" seems to be explaining what the experiment is, or is explaining the experiment.

Some quick examples I came up with:

> This experiment involves measuring the size of a balloon at different temperatures.  Try this physical experiment:
>
> 1. Heat [the balloon] so that it expands.

versus

> In order to see how temperature impacts kinetic energy, try this physical experiment: "heating [a balloon]".